# What is the dimension of an Instanton?

Tags: string-theory, gauge-theory, spacetime-dimensions, branes, instantons

My thought process about this question was this:
A point particle couples to a $p=1$-Form field and is itself $p-1=0$-dimensional.
A string couples to a $p=2$-Form field an is $p-1=1$ dimensional.
An Instanton however is a point in spacetime, meaning it couples to a $0$-Form field. Does this mean that it is a $p-1=-1$ dimensional object and if yes, how can I imagine it? Would this imply that I don’t need any information to know where it is located at any time?

Comment: I think you can think of an instanton as a spacetime event of creating (or annihilating) a certain particle.

Comment: I don’t quite get it, could you elaborate?